# Como carregar dados para o MySQL mais rapidamente?

Tags: mysql, csv

Tenho um DER que representa um aeroporto e tenho de carregar para lá dados provenientes de vários csv. por exemplo tenho uma ligação de 1 para muitos, de avião para voos. Se eu tiver esta tabela ligada com a chave estrangeira dá me erro a carregar os dados pelo que não inseri ligações. Estou então a fazer por joins.
Estou a fazer a seguinte consulta:

```
Use tese;
create table aviao1 
(select a.tailnum, a.type, a.manufacturer, a.issue_data, a.model, a.status, a.aircraft_type, a.engine_type, a.year, c.uniquecarrier 

From aviao a

INNER JOIN voos c

ON a.tailnum = c.tailnum )
```

A *tail number* é a minha chave primária na tabela aviao e na tabela voo é a minha chave estrangeira. Ambas estão contidas nos csv avião e voo. Sendo assim vejo quais correspondem e crio uma nova tabela avião com as chaves que condizem. O problema é quando vou fazer a consulta, já está ha mais de 9 horas a correr e ainda não acabou. É normal demorar tanto tempo ou existe uma maneira de tornar este processo mais rápido?

Comment: Remova chave primária, índices e quaisquer outras constraints que criam índices (como `UNIQUE`). Após a importação dos dados, adicione as constraints. Não vou colocar como resposta pois não sei como fazer isso em MySQL.

Comment: Não seria um problema de load do seu servidor?

Comment: Então carrego tudo primeiro sem definir quaisquer chaves primárias ou secundárias? Em relação às unique eu na importação tenho de selecionar isso senão carrega-me campos repetidos :/ Depois de inserir os dados nas tabelas posso então liga los através das chaves sem fazer o inner join? O mysql faz isso automaticamente quando seleciono qual a chave estrangeira?

Comment: Não porque já fiz com menos dados e carrega rápido (2 h máximo).

Answer (score 1):

O comando `load data infile` carrega muito rapidamente dados de um arquivo `CSV`. Como você possui chaves estrangeiras, pode desligar a verificação antes de executar o comando e ligar novamente depois. Ficaria algo como:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0; 
LOAD DATA INFILE ... ; 
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Podias explicar um pouco ou adicionar uma breve descrição do que é este código @alastori ? Assim como a resposta está, parece estar um bocado 'vaga'.

Comment: Tem razão. Resposta editada.

Comment: Só mais uma dica, para formatar código e texto, você pode dar uma olhada **[nesta página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)** e também **[nesta página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** para saber como fazer isso :)